# Given an analytic continuation along $\gamma$ such that $R(t)\equiv \infty$ for some $t$, then $R(s)\equiv \infty$ for each $s\in [0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, analytic-continuation

> **Definition:** A *function element* is a pair $(f,U)$ where $U$ is a region and $f$ is an  anaytic function on   $U$. For a given function element $(f,U)$ define the *germ of $f$ at $a$*  to be the collection of all function elements $(g,v)$ such that $a\in V$ and $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z$ in a neighborhood of $a$. Denote the germ by $\left[f\right]_a$.

This allows to define the following

> **Definition** Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a path and suppose that for each $t\in [0,1]$ there is  a function element $(f_t,U_t)$ such that:
>
> 1. $\gamma(t)\in U_t$.
> 2. for each $t\in [0,1]$ there is $\delta >0$ such that $\left|s-t\right|<\delta$ implies $\gamma(s)\in U_t$ and $$\left[f_s\right]_{\gamma(s)}=\left[f_t\right]_{\gamma(s)}.$$
>
> Then $(f_1,U_1)$ is the *analytic continuation of $(f_0,U_0)$ along the path $\gamma$*.

The above definitions were introduced to contextualize my question:

**My Question:** Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a path and let $\left\{(f_t,U_t)\: : 0\leq t\leq 1\right\}$ be an analytic continuation along $\gamma$. For $0\leq t\leq 1$ let $R(t)$ be the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f_t$ about $z=\gamma(t)$. Suppose that $R(t)\equiv \infty$ for some value value of $t$. **Can I say $R(s)\equiv \infty$ for each $s\in [0,1]$?**

Comment: Yes, as any germs on $\gamma$ should coincide with the germ $(f_t,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: That is precisely my question, why any germs on $\gamma$ should coincide with the germ $(f_t,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: As any path inside the domain of a function element should have the same germ forced by that function element. This follows from the uniqueness of the analytic continuation aling fixed curve. And in this case the domain of the particular function elt is $￦mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In the definition of 'function element' it does not say that $U$ is the largest region where $f$ is analytical, so I can not say $(f_t,\mathbb{C})$ is in the analytic continuation. Though I can say that $f$ is an entire function.

Comment: You're right but uniqueness of analytic continuation means the "germ-valued" curve with initial value is unique and not depend on the choice of covering of that curve with domains of function elts so it doesn't matter the domain is large or small.